# Is there a better way to pass data to a custom keyboard view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to Swift and SwiftUI (and programming in general).

I'm trying to build an app about statistics, and because of these specific needs, I had to write a custom keyboard with numbers and basic operations. The problem is that I want to store the X values and Y values in two different arrays so I have to call my "ChartKeyboard" two times: one for writing the X values and other time for the Y values. Here is the code I use to call the keyboard:

```
Group {
                if isXorYSelected == .x {
                    ChartKeyboard(isShown: $keyShown, txtInput: $sampleData.XValues[arrayPosition])
                }
                if isXorYSelected == .y {
                    ChartKeyboard(isShown: $keyShown, txtInput: $sampleData.YValues[arrayPosition])
                }
            }
```

The data is stored in a custom ChartData object:

```
struct ChartDataObject: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    
    var name: String
    let date: Date
    var regType: regressionType
    
    var dataX: [Double]
    var dataY: [Double]
    
    var regressionCoef: Double
    var slope: Double
    var origin: Double
    
}
```

And some of the state variables in case you wonder:

```
struct NewChart: View {
    
    @State var keyShown = false
    
    @State var sampleData = XYData(XValues: [" "], YValues: [" "])
    
    var newChartType = ["Standard Addition", "External Standard","Internal Standard"]
    @State private var selectedChartType = 0
    
    /*
     Types are:
     1 = Standard Addition
     2 = External Standard
     3 = Internal Standard
     */
    
    @State var newChartTitle = ""
    @State var newChartDate = Date()
    
    @State var isXorYSelected = isXorY.x
    
    @State var arrayPosition = 0

(...)
```

The result is a weird animation when changing from isXorYSelected from .x to .y:

[image: CustomKeyboard weird animation]

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to see the code where the `ChartKeyboard` is actually used (or be able to test this with an example), but here's a guess: what happens if you use a ternary expression for `txtInput`: `txtInput: isXorYSelected == .x ? $sampleData.XValues[arrayPosition] : $sampleData.YValues[arrayPosition]`

Comment: Thanks! That worked just as I wanted it to be!

Comment: Great -- I added it as an answer. You can accept it by clicking the green checkmark. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the view within the `if` clause is probably causing it to be redrawn. Instead, you can change the parameter with a ternary expression:

```
ChartKeyboard(isShown: $keyShown, txtInput: isXorYSelected == .x ? $sampleData.XValues[arrayPosition] : $sampleData.YValues[arrayPosition])
```